# Interpreting Sentinel 1 Imagery from Alaska Satellite Facility

Tags: sentinel-1

The Alaska Satellite Facility's Vertex data portal provides Sentinel 1A/B data, and for some granules they also provide false coloring. Is there some documentation or idea of how they do this coloration?

Here is an example with the following granule (from March 9, 2018). Is it delineating ice from water here?

S1A_IW_OCN__2SDV_20180309T171806_20180309T171831_020941_023EFA_5CE0

[image: Sentinel 1 Granule over Alaska on 2018 03 09]

Comment: How do you access the false color image? Using vertex and the granule I am unable to see any false color images displayed.

Comment: Kersten, I've repeated the search and this specific granule no longer has a displayed image. Using their geospatial search, if you look for Sentinel 1A/B data over this area (this is the Yukon River Delta), you'll see a number of granules pop up from 2014 onwards, both from IW & EW. Link here: https://vertex.daac.asf.alaska.edu/